# How can a create a #define to create a 2d vector?

Tags: c++, vector, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to have a `#define` statement which does the following:

for a simple vector i can do this:

```
#define dvec std::vector<double>
dvec x1d(n)
```

note that instantiating it is just the same as for a normal vector. But for 2d vectors, it's not as nice:

```
#define dvec2d std:vector<std:vector<double>>
dvec2d x2d(n, std:vector<double>(m))
```

How would I create a define so that all I need to do to instantiate dvec2d be this:

```
dvec2d x2d(n, m)
```

Sure, I can do this:

```
dvec2d x2d(n, std:vector<double>(m))
```

each time i want to create one of these, but i'd rather not have that extra `std:vector<double>` in there - it would be neater if i could just have `dvec2d x2d(n, m)`.

EDIT: To clarify, I know i can create a function to give me the vector, or a typedef, that's not what i'm after. The people using the functions are going to be chucking `vector<vector<double>>` into them, so that's what they need to be. But i don't want to have function definitions that are massive because of all of definitions in there. Using the `#define dvec2d ...` gets around that.

Now, when i'm testing my stuff, i need to create 2d vectors. I know i can do it with `dvec2d my2dVector(n, std::vector<double>(m))`, but what i want to know is if there is any way i can write a `#define` such that i can create these guys like this: `dvec2d my2dVector(n,m)`?

Comment: Use a `typedef` instead. Macros are bad and prone to generate obscure errors. Also you would need a parameterized macro, won't you?

Comment: I'm using macros so that the functions i write can still use `vector<vector<double>>` outside, but i'd just like it to be cleaner inside the code. I'm not going to be creating many of these, but i just wanted to know how i would do it...

Comment: If `n` and `m` are variables, use an inline function. Much cleaner than a macro.

Comment: Macros could support syntax like `dvec2d(n, m, x2d)`, with also the  variable name given as macro parameter. However, you really don't want to be using macros for this kind of purposes! I would consider adding to your question: "Or how can I do this without macros?".

Comment: Using a `typedef` would be far better.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a macro you can use a template function.  You can make a `make_2d_vector` function like:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> make_2d_vector(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)
{
    return std::vector<std::vector<T>>(rows, std::vector<T>(cols));
}
```

Then when you want to create a 2d vector you can use:

```
auto foo = make_2d_vector<double>(5,10);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8283f60830fa75fb)</kbd>

As pointed out by [Nipheris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3927447/nipheris) if you do not have access to `auto` you could always create a `typedef` like:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> vector2d;
vector2d foo = make_2d_vector<double>(5,10);
```

Comment: @hyde typedef can help in case of old compiler. Why not use "vector2d"?

Comment: @hyde _", the syntax becomes quite ugly"_ What's actually ugly with `std::vector<std::vector<double>> foo`?? Especially as the OP stated they explicitly want to use that syntax?

Comment: @hyde No, that's the job of the template function parameters :-P ... If we talk about fixed sized stuff `std::array` should be used instead of `std::vector` which really require the current standard.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So you meant `std::vector<std::vector<double>> foo = make_2d_vector<double>(5,10);`, I assume. I consider that to be quite ugly. YMMV.